# Swiched off power during suspend, now only booting into emergency mode

Tags: boot, hardware

I have had problems with going into suspend sometimes (every 10th time or so), with the system never actually turning off (black screen forever, PSU running).  Usually, then, I just manually turned it off then by pressing the power button longer.  Yesterday, this phenomenon happened again, and this time for some reason I just turned off the switch on the power strip.  Now Ubuntu only boots into emergency mode.

My observations until now:

- The "wait screen" takes longer than usual, and then I end up in emergency mode with warnings like [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/267172/linux-mint-acpi-pcc-probe-and-usb-descriptor-errors-during-boot):

  ```
  [21.3186(or 06)50] ACPI: _SB_.PCI0.SBRG.ASOC: Device cannot be configured due to a frequency mismatch.
  ```

  and I have seen

  ```
  [2.135031] usb 4-2: device descriptor read/all, error -71.
  ```

  the first time emergency mode occured.  I don't know whether those have anything to to with my problems, though -- the only PCI device that's plugged into a slot is the graphics card, some 10 year old one.  (I dedusted everything, and removed and reinserted it, nothing changed).  Also, graphics *are* obviously working, since I am using the screen.

  It also says

  ```
  /dev/sda2: clean xx/yy files, zz/ww blocks
  ```

  where `/dev/sda2` is the root partition.
- `systemctl default` just takes some time and ends in emergency mode again.
- I managed to boot into Xubuntu from a live CD, without detecting any problems.  All hard discs seem to be OK (Gparted didn't complain, `lsblk` listed them), and I mounted the root partition to disable the `tmpfs` and swap partitions in the `fstab`.
- From the Xubuntu, I ran `hw-probe` with [this result](https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=dc448a83c5), where everything seems to be present and working.
- I didn't notice any obvious errors in `journalctl -xc`, but then I'm not really experienced with log outputs.  Some noticeable things:

  ```
  systemd[1]: Startup finished in ...; Subject: System start-up is now complete
  ```

  (this made me wonder what could be wrong at all...)

  ```
  systemd[1]: System is tainted: local-hwclock; Subject: the system is configured in a way that might cause problems

  systmed[1]: dev-disk-by\bla\bla\bla\bla.device: Job dev-disk-by\bla\bla\bla.device timed out
  ```

  where the last `bla` seems to be the UUID for some partition.

  Additionally, some disk timouts happened for disk names that are obviously from external disks in the `fstab` but unplugged, so I ignored these.
- Grub works, I can go into recovery mode, but haven't found it useful.  (Also, the menu of it is somewhat interleaved with terminal text, and you have to press keys twice to enter text.  But other than that, recovery mode is working.)

Now I'm out of ideas what to even diagnose.  Any suggestions how to get the PC running again without having to work from a live stick always?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to have been some strange file system or partitioning issue.  After commenting out all partitions except `/` in the fstab, I could boot normally, except for `/home` being present, of course.  All partitions did (where possible) check fine with Gparted's file system checking utility.

Reactivating all partitions one after the other, I found out -- nothing.  It just works again.

Whatever that was...

---

Update: the fact that the mainboard failed one day after this experience likely has something to do with this.